# Time Zone Issue on Mac

Tags: ios, timezone, zone

I have  created an Application in MVC which will be globally worlwide. Now I need to mange the timezone for all user. I have managed the same via find the time zone information  by findtimezonebyname("Indian Standard Time") and I am getting this string "Indian Standard Time" from clicnt side function but on MAC I am getting "IST"  so how can I get "Indian Standard Time" from Mac also.

Comment: Timezone info: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info  This link explains that Windows lives in its own world of (non-portable) timezones.

Comment: Here is a 3rd party, free, open-source, portable (VS-2015 or higher recommended) time zone library that uses the IANA time zone database on all platforms: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html

Comment: Dup is based on infering that by "Application in MVC" you meant ASP.Net Core.  If not, please describe your environment better.  Thanks.